# Windows Service System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, io

I have a windows service written in C# .NET that among some other things will copy a file from my local computer(ie the computer that runs the service) to an other computer on the same network, but when I run the copy command (SYSTEM.IO.File.Copy(sourcePath, destpath)) I get the errormessage 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException'. I have permission to the 'destPath' since I can copy files with Win Explorer.

I would be very greatful if someone has a solution of this problem.

Comment: `NotFound` would mean that your path in code is wrong. Its not the permission issue. I think.

Comment: Please show the code you use to copy the files.

Comment: Just because you have permission does not mean the service does.  Make sure the account the service is running as has permission.

Answer (score 0):

This can **only** occur because either the source or destination paths don't exist. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx):

> The path specified in sourceFileName or destFileName is invalid (for example, it is on an unmapped drive).

Unfortunately, without a lot of runtime information, and your code, there would be no way for us to know which is wrong. Further, even with that, it's going to be hard. The bottom line, one of the paths doesn't exist.

**NOTE:** if the destination doesn't exist, it doesn't get created. You need to check that *before* trying to copy and then use `Directory.CreateDirectory` to ensure it exists.